# Order Filtered Results by Total Occurrence

Tags: python, django

I am currently working on a search for my Django site and want to take a query then see how many time it appears in a posts name and description and return the results with the posts with the query appearing the most on top (ie if I search for "car" a post with car mentioned 5 time should appear before a post that mentions "car" once).

Here is my views.py:

```
def stack_list(request, query):
    context_dict = {}

    stacks_list = Stack.objects.filter(
        Q(name__icontains=query) | 
        Q(description__icontains=query)
    ).annotate(total_occurance=Count('name')+Count('description')
    ).order_by('total_occurance').distinct()

    context_dict['stacks_list'] = stacks_list

    return render(request, 'stack/index_search_results.html', context_dict)
```

and my html:

```
{% for stack in stacks_list %}
    <p>{{ stack.name }}
    {{ stack.description }}</p>
{% endfor %}
```

However when I try a query, it doesn't organize it in descending order. Any ideas on where I'm going wrong?

Comment: Is it on ascending order? Or not ordered at?

Comment: It doesn't seem to be ordered at all

Comment: Try to remove the `.distinct()`. It seems there is an issue when you use distinct with order_by. (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/models/querysets/#distinct)

Comment: Ok, I removed it, still doesn't seem to change anything though

Answer (score 0):

Why not to use ad hoc tools for search purposes? For example, [Django Postgres full text search](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/contrib/postgres/search/#full-text-search) or [Django Haystack](http://haystacksearch.org/) for more complex search and faceting(in my opinion this tool have some disadvantages - so, when i'm working with elasticsearch, i use [Elasticsearch DSL](http://elasticsearch-dsl.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html) python library). Hope it helps, sorry if you trying solve case exact this way for some educational reason.

Comment: Yea I'm looking into haystack, thanks for the other options though I'll definitely look through them now. I'm a bit of a noob at search but is there much of a difference (in large sites) with using a third part tool like haystack or Elasticsearch DSL vs filtering in views?

Comment: Yes, of course. Search engines like elasticsearch or sphinx gives you much more flexibility and power in queries, a lot of metrics, filters, sorting options, aggregations. And most important, it's scoring search results. But in small projects it can be redurdant, and hard to manage engine server, indicies, so I recommend try django's full text search suport for postgres. In large prjects you definitely should use separate solution.

Comment: ```Stack.objects.filter(
    Q(name__icontains=query) | Q(description__icontains=query)
).annotate(
    name_occurance=Count('name'),
    desc_occurance = Count('description'),
    total_occurance = Sum('name_occurance', 'desc_occurance')
).order_by('total_occurance')```